# Passing arguments to stored procedures MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I've created procedure with IN parameter inside my database(MySql->Routines->Create Procedure).
I am using it to create a new database. When i call the procedure and pass argument,
the new database is created but the name of the new database is the name of the variable that i use in the procedure and not the name that i pass as a parameter.

> CREATE  PROCEDURE dbCreate (IN dbName VARCHAR(255))
>
> BEGIN
>
> ```
>     CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS dbName COLLATE utf8_bin;
>     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbName.City(
>     .
>     .
>     .
>     );
> ```

When i call the procedure dbCreate,

> USE old_database;
>
> CALL old_database.dbCreate('FRANCE');

MySql generates new database which is called dbName.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363415/why-cant-i-use-a-variable-as-the-table-name-in-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct your statement as if it was a string:

```
SET @s = CONCAT('USE old_database; CALL old_database.dbCreate(', dbName,');');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: I tried using the above statement but i receive an error: "Unknown column in the field list". I used single quotes to create the string

Comment: CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `dbCreate`(IN dbName
VARCHAR(255))

BEGIN
 SET @x='CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ? COLLATE utf8_bin';
 PREPARE statement FROM @x;
 EXECUTE statement USING @dbName;
this code sets variable dbName to the parameter that i pass, but now i receive syntax error 1064 when i try to execute the procedure

Comment: Solved. I used the CONCAT function for all the tables in database.