# Can I use a MySQL variable to name a table?

Tags: mysql

I've got a workflow that requires me to keep a bunch of tables with different names like

```
2012_10_15_ncvoter68
2012_11_15_ncvoter68
2012_12_15_ncvoter68
```

You get the idea.

Let's say that I've just created the table `2012_12_15_ncvoter68`.

I would like to query this table using a variable. E.g., I could define a variable:

```
SET @dt_ncv = CONCAT((SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y_%m_%d')),"_ncvoter68");
```

The variable `@dt_ncv` evaluates to the string `2012_12_15_ncvoter68`.

But I can't figure out how (or if it's possible) to use this variable to reference the table.

The query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM @dt_ncv;
```

simply give a SQL syntax error.

I've tried playing with prepared statements but that didn't seem to help.

I hope some of you MySQL gurus can help!

Comment: Having a different table for each month is bad design - why not just have a single table with a date column?

Comment: semi dupe, same solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363415/why-cant-i-use-a-variable-as-the-table-name-in-a-stored-procedure/8363487#8363487

Answer (score 5):

I looked through my old MySQL notes and found a way to do it:

```
SET @dt_ncv = CONCAT((SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y_%m_%d')),"_ncvoter68");
SET @cntstmt = CONCAT_WS(" ", "SELECT count(*) FROM",@dt_ncv);
PREPARE ncv_count_stmt FROM @cntstmt;
EXECUTE ncv_count_stmt;
```

It's not pretty and it's not concise, but it works!

Comment: I agree it's not pretty, and it shouldn't be necessary if you made date (or month) a column in your data table. A little refactoring and you could have a much easier to use design.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't do that.

You'll have to handle the variable substitutions in a procedural language.

As the manual says (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html)

> User variables are intended to provide data values. They cannot be
>   used directly in an SQL statement as an identifier or as part of an
>   identifier, such as in contexts where a table or database name is
>   expected, or as a reserved word such as SELECT.

Comment: You can do the variable substitution in sql by using dynamic sql by using a prepared statement to kludge execution of the string.