# How to use JOIN when the table name and the column name is stored in another table?

Tags: sql, join

I need to write a query that requires a join to another table but both table name and the column name are stored in another table.

I have two tables as listed below:

Table "description_tab" : (id, type_id, reference_id, name, description)

Table "description_tab_type" : (id, type_name, reference_table, reference_column_name, reference_column_id)

where description_tab_type contains the name of other table and the two columns I need for JOIN.

I tried dynamic SQL:

```
SELECT reference_table, reference_column_name, reference_column_id 
INTO @reference_table, @reference_column_name, @reference_column_id 
FROM description_tab_type WHERE type_name = 'Origin'; 

PREPARE statement FROM "select dt.description from description_tab dt join @reference_table on @reference_table.@reference_column_id = dt.reference_id where @reference_table.@reference_column_name = 'test'";

EXECUTE statement;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
```

but it didn't work. When I run it i get the following:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@reference_table on @reference_table.@reference_column_id =
>   dt.reference_id  where @refere' at line 1

any suggestions ?

Comment: the sql string is wrong, use concat(). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363415/why-cant-i-use-a-variable-as-the-table-name-in-a-stored-procedure/8363487#8363487

Comment: dynamic SQL statement is the only way out here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think MySQL will do what you want in one statement. (Actually, I think it's outside the SQL syntax).

I think you'll need to do this in three steps:

```
1) Query the reference table for the table and column names you need

2) Assemble the query by concatenating it around the values you retrieved in step 1

3) Submit/Prepare the new query.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up the variable first:

```
set @query = concat('select dt.description from description_tab dt join ',
                    @reference_table, ' r ',
                    'on r.', @reference_column_id, ' = dt.reference_id '
                    'where rt.', @reference_column_name = \'test\''
                   );



PREPARE statement FROM @query;

EXECUTE statement;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the prepare statement, but try this:

Execute ('select dt.description from description_tab dt join ' + @reference_table + ' on ' + @reference_table + '.' + @reference_column_id + ' = dt.reference_id where ' +  @reference_table + '.' + @reference_column_name + ' = ''test''');