# oracle native dynamic sql join a tabled named in another

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to join 2 tables, the main table will contain a column that tells me what sub table to join to.
I found this question, but I don't think it's applicable to Oracle.

[How to use JOIN when the table name and the column name is stored in another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517376/how-to-use-join-when-the-table-name-and-the-column-name-is-stored-in-another-tab)

Example

- TableA (Year:Int, batch:Int, Job:Int)
- TableB13 (batch:int, amount:int)
- TableB12 (batch:int, amout:int)
- etc...

So we have many yeared tables, and I need to use the year from the TableA to select the appropriate related table.
From my research I have come the the conclusion that this is possible using Native dynamic Sql, however I have not managed to get it working.

Here is what I need to do

```
Select tA.batch, tB.amount  from tableA ta, tableB'tA.year' tB
WHERE tA.batch = '1234'
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but it shows what I want.
I tried something like the below,

```
create or replace procedure QUERY_INVOICE (
         i_batch in varchar2,
         i_year in varchar2,
         o_cursor out sys_refcursor)

 as
 begin
    open o_cursor for
     'select amount from tableB' || i_year || ' where batch = ' || i_batch;
 end;
 / 
variable rc refcursor;
exec system.query_invoice('52786','12', :rc);
print rc;
```

Although the correct records from the correct table print, I still need to know how to make this work where the Year and Batch come from tableA and not hard coded.

```
select * from TableA, query_invoice(tableA.batch, tableA.year)
```

I also thought about creating a view, and using a UNION on all the tables. There are about 20 years of tables and creating the UNION takes a while. And I'm worried about performance when I use the view. Also I would have to remember to modify the view every year to add a new year table.

In all past systems I've worked on, all data was always in 1 table with a year or date column. Having separate tables per year is driving me nuts as it's over complicating what should be a very simple select. Unless I am missing something, is there a fairly straight forward way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: I cant give you oracle syntax but you'll need to use dynamic sql, getting the name of the table stored in a column into a variable, and using this to build up a string which is then executed to get the result.

Comment: If you can come up with a query to get the year and batch you want from tableA, without reference to tableB, then all you need to do is add an `INTO` clause to that query, directing the results into `i_year` and `i_batch`. If not then maybe you need to clarify something